# How to cancel hiding a Devexpress flyoutpanel according to a condition?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have a [FlyoutPanel](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114578/controls-and-libraries/messages-notifications-and-dialogs/flyout-panel) and I want to hide it according to a condition.
For example: I want to hide it when a counter is equal to 3.
What I have tried is:

```
private void flyoutPanel1_BeforeHide(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (globalCounter == 3)
        flyoutPanel1.HideBeakForm();
    else
    {
        globalCounter++;
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

The problem is:
`flyoutPanel1_BeforeHide` only called once, after it sees `e.Cancel=true;` it will never called again.
I want this method to be called whenever I try to hide the flyoutpanel.
Is the problem is with my code or its a bug with Devexpress?
Iam using c# winforms with the latest version of [Devexpress Winforms](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/)

Comment: I don't have their docs in front of me, but tons of experience.  I presume e.Cancel is literally telling the flyout panel not to hide.  Isn't this expected or am I missing something?  That said DevExpress does provide source code so that should make figuring it out easier.

Comment: @Zer0 You are right, it tells not to hide, but not to hide forever!?
flyoutPanel1_BeforeHide not called again when it sees e.Cancel=true once

Comment: Any chance you can provide an MRE?  Small code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Sorry iam poor in english, i dont know exactly what do you mean, But i have showen a MessageBox.Show("Called"); inside _BeforeHide method, which indicates it only called once

Comment: Can you write small code I can copy and paste to run on my side that shows the issue?  Something simple.  Could find you a fix quickly that way.

Comment: @Zer0 Here is a sample project
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14WxFsCgcHDl6DSrRPWlZpEemEFjOgimu/view?usp=sharing